# How to use will_paginate gem with Sinatra and Sequel

Tags: ruby, sinatra, will-paginate, sequel, pagination

I am trying to use the will_paginate gem to paginate my blog posts, i am also using Sinatra and Sequel for the blog. I receive an error stating

```
"undefined method `paginate'"
```

And I have tried everything to make it work, but it's always the same error.

```
page = params.fetch "page", 1
per_page = params.fetch "per_page", 3
@posts = Post.order(:id).paginate(page.to_i,per_page.to_i)
```

or

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Both produce the same error no matter which query I provide.

Is there any way to make this work, or is there any other way so I could paginate my posts using Sequel and Sinatra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not specifically Sequel-related, but you can paginate any collection (even those will_paginate doesn't integrate with by default) using this:

```
require 'will_paginate/collection'
paged_collection =
  WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, total_count) do |pager|
    pager.replace(collection)
  end
```

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
require 'will_paginate'
require 'will_paginate/sequel'
require 'sequel/extensions/pagination'

page = params.fetch "page", 1
per_page = params.fetch "per_page", 3
@posts = Post.order(:id).extension(:pagination).paginate(page.to_i,per_page.to_i)
```

Comment: I am new to Ruby in overall, this is my first project with it. So can you be more specific please ? ..i can send you my code and try to work this together ...

Comment: More specific? This is pretty much plug-and-play. Put `Post.order(:id)` for `collection`, `to_i` what you have to `to_i`, and replace `paged_collection` with `@posts`. If you don't know `total_count`, you can leave it off. Where specifically do you have a problem?

Comment: So after i declare 'page' and 'per_page' as i did in the main question ( i am leaving off total_count ), and i write -" @posts = WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page) do |pager|, pager.replace(Post.order(:id)), end "- i receive an error stating "no implicit conversion of Sequel::SQLite::Dataset into Array" ..p.s. THANK YOU FOR YOU PATIENCE

Comment: Okay, upon a bit more research on Sequel, seems a) your code does not actually return rows, and b) will_paginate does support Sequel, so... I'll update the answer.

Comment: I could not check it till now. And YES it does seem to paginate the posts. But I have one more issue, for example I have 9 posts, and i make them to show 3 per page as in the example, so where are the other 6 posts located, what is the URL for browsing them now ? ..THANK YOU for all your help though, you are being really helpful.

Comment: The pagination links are created by `<%= will_paginate @posts %>` (in ERB, or `= will_paginate @posts` in HAML...)

Comment: hmm, One more thing though. I did all the pagination code in the main route ( '/' ), and after i put the pagination link code given in ur comment everything works, except that whenever i try to access any other route, i receive an error stating " undefined method `total_pages' for nil:NilClass " .I dont understand it now ??

Comment: Hm, can't test now, and the docs say that `total_pages` (the third argument to `paginate`) is optional... Or wait, does it work for one route and not for others? Are you trying to `will_paginate` in a view called from a route that doesn't set `@posts`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was not around ..i just put the will_paginate to the view that was displaying each post in the view, and not in the layout.erb and everything went fine ..THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP!